# Is there a way to define a timeout based on the url?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, timeout, weblogic

I am looking for a solution for timeout passing to my application with minimum code injection in it.

So, is there a way to pass timeout parameter to a connection based on url prefix? Spring and weblogic included solutions are needed.

Comment: Read timeout or connect timeout? You can do this via the URLConnection.setReadTimeout and URLConnection.setConnectTimeout methods.

Comment: Yeah but I have plenty of webservices and I am looking for a simple and fast way

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way to pass timeout parameter to a connection based on url prefix?

Not that I've heard of.  Certainly the URL, URI and HTTP specs don't provide a standard way to include timeout as part of a request.

> Spring and weblogic included solutions are needed.

See above.  I've never heard of any general (or Spring or Weblogic specific) solutions that allow you to do this via the URL.

---

> Any ideas?

It would help if you were more specific about the problem you were trying to solve.

What kind of timeout you are talking about?  Client-side timeout on connect?  Client-side timeout on receipt of a response?  Some kind of server-side timeout?

What is the use-case?

What are the constraints?

Comment: I am trying to add timeout parameters to webservices which application uses. To add configuration or implementation to each web service object will be difficultt, will be needed so many time to implement and to test. So I need this kind of a solution.